# fb like button not showing on any browser except chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I've used the iframe code to display the fb like button on a site I am developing, usually it turns out right for all browser but this on only display on chrome.

I tried using html5 and xfbml still doesn't show on other browsers.

Tried fixing height and width on the css span on the html5 version still doesn't show up.

It reads `height:0;` and `width:0;` and on chrome `height:21;` and `width:73;`

**Why is that happening?**

I've also noticed that when I enter the fb page url in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
the preview doesnt show up. Tried other pages and it shows the preview.

**Does this have something to with why it's not showing on other browsers?**

Here is the iframe code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FCarolina-Designer-Cabinets%2F400436533396747&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Here is the site
http://carolinadesignercabinets.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's weird, looks like a specific issue with your layout (could be either CSS, JS or HTML) that causes this. Also looks like the iframe inner code is not rendering properly on non-chrome browsers. In any case, Facebook has announced iframe as deprecated, so I suggest you move to their updated code and see if it works out. In your case:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Carolina-Designer-Cabinets/400436533396747" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

You might need to include the following JS on the bottom of your page, if you haven't already.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=465232306855359";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: I've tried that just now still doesn't work. There is just one thing is noticed on non chrome browsers. They render the span undre fb-like div with <span style="height: 0px; width: 0px;">. I've read from other forums that they just adjusted these values via css, but still didn't work on mine.